# Bind ListView to list of numeric value types?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

My googling is failing me this Monday morning.  This should be simple, can someone help?

Normally I bind ListView an object collection as in:

```
    <ListView Margin="5,10,5,10" x:Name="listViewFoo" ItemsSource="{Binding FooCollection}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="FooBar" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FooProperty}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

How can I bind ItemsSource to a collection of say, System.Int64 objects and display them in one column?

Comment: Are you sure you want a GridView in a ListView? And a `List<Int64>` will not have a FooProperty for binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `DisplayMemberBinding`; this should work...

```
    <ListView Margin="5,10,5,10" x:Name="listViewFoo" ItemsSource="{Binding FooCollection}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="FooBar"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  Just deleted DisplayMemberBinding in the GridViewColumn.